# how to write this LINQ query of 3 tables?

Tags: c#, linq

- Table1 CAR (CARID, CarModelID ,CARuniqueinfo1, CARUniqueinfo2): contians all cars have been entered to the warehouse.
- Table2 CarModel (CarModelID ,Modelinfo1 ,Modelinfo2 )
- Table3 Sale (SaleID, CarID, clientID, EmpID)

What is the Linq Query that returns :

number of sold cars only for ModelID=101

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Way:

```
var result =
    db.Sale
        .GroupBy(item => item.CarId)
        .Select(item => new { item.Key, item.Count() });
```

Nice way:

```
var result =
    from sale in db.Sale

    join car in db.CAR
    on car.CARID equals sale.CarID

    join carModel in db.CarModel
    on carModel.CarModelID equals car.CarModelID

    select new 
    { 
        Model = carModel,
        SoldCars = db.Sale.Count(item => item.CarID == car.CARID)
    };
```

Comment: sory >> I want the number of sold cars for ModelID= 102

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a navigation propertiy for `Sale(CarID)`:

```
int all = db.Models
            .Where(m => m.Cars.SelectMany(c => c.Sales).Any())
            .Select(m => new {m.ModelID, m.Cars.Count}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I want count of sold cars only

Comment: I want the number of sold cars only of each Model

Comment: @user1806254, edited. Assuming you have navigation propertiy for `Sale(CarID)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var counts = Model.GroupBy(m => m.CarModelID)
                  .Select(grp => ModelId = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count())
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Dictionary<int, int> carsSold = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (Car in Cars) {
 carrsold.Add(x => x.Id, Sales.Where(y => y.CarId == x.Id).Count());
}
```

will leave you with a dictionary that maps car id to amount sold.

`carsSold[1]` would return amount sold by the car with id of 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int GetCarsSoldCount(int modelId)
{
  return db.Sale.Count(x => x.CarID == modelId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var r = from car in CarTable
                from sale in SalesTable
                where sale.CarID == car.CarID
                group sale by car.CarModelID into g
                select new { Model = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```